# How to perform an active record search based on a regular expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, activerecord

I have a standard `User` model in my rails app. Complete with First Name, Last Name, Email, etc. I am attempting to search for all Users that meet a certain criteria.

I know that I can search for a specific email address as follows:

```
User.find_by_email('john@smith.com')
```

But say I want to find all users that have a Gmail address (for example). Ideally this would be done via:

```
User.find_by_email(/.*@gmail.com/)
```

But that doesn't work. It gives me a `TypeError: Cannot visit Regexp`. How can I perform this activerecord search?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`.find(_by)` only returns the first match. Since you want to find *all* users with a Gmail address you need to use `.where`.

You can easily combine the query with some regex:

**With Mysql**, use [`REGEXP`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-regexp-function.php)

```
User.where("email REGEXP ?", '.*@gmail.com')
```

**With Postgres**, use [`regexp_matches`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html):

```
User.where("regexp_matches(email, ?)", '.*@gmail.com')
```

Comment: PostgreSQL 11 not supporting **REGEXP**

Answer (score 5):

In your specific case, you are looking for a string ending in a known substring: `.*@gmail.com`

You don't need regexps for that. A `LIKE` search is sufficient and faster:

```
User.where("email LIKE ?", '%@gmail.com')
```

Answer (score 3):

As of PostgreSQL Ver.14, @davegson's answer does not work with Postgres. Here are two ways – for case-insensitive matching, as email addresses should be:

```rb
User.where("email ~* ?", '^.*@gmail.com$')
  # "~" for case-sensitive match
User.where("regexp_match(email, ?, ?) IS NOT NULL", '.*@gmail.com', 'i')

# Wrong way
User.where("regexp_matches(email, ?)", '.*@gmail.com')
 # => ERROR:  set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE (PG::FeatureNotSupported)
```

[PostgreSQL official docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)